# Is it possible to do a 2sls with linear regression in the 1st stage and logistic regression in the 2nd stage?

Tags: logistic, logit, instrumental-variables, endogeneity, 2sls

I'm working on a a bivariate logistic regression. But I have an endogeneity problem and I want solve it through 2sls with 2 instrumental variables.

My thought was to regress (OLS) in first stage and later a bilogit in second stage. Is this a suitable analysis? Is it a "forbidden regression"? What would be the best option that helps to solve it?

Comment: If your only question is about (the existence of R) code, it is off topic here. If you have a statistical question about 2sls when 1 stage is a binary variable, please edit to clarify.

Comment: I see what you mean. Ok. On other hand,  to carry out a 2sls with ols in 1st stage and logit in 2nd is a "forbbiden regression", isn't it?

thanks for you answer, gung.

Comment: If you have a statistical question about 2sls when 1 stage is a binary variable, please edit your question to focus on that. Otherwise, this will end up being closed.

Comment: I've edited question, gung

Comment: This question is now on topic here. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: thanks, gung...and sorry for my english, it's not my native language, however I'm learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer : No, you can't. That is indeed forbidden regression what you're trying to do.

Possible solutions : some brief discussion, google the keywords to learn more.

1. Use LPM(linear probability model) - just use regular 2SLS with your data. sounds crazy, but a lot of people do this in economics literature. Make sure that you get the standard errors right.
2. MLE - specify the distribution of your first stage equation, jointly with the second stage binary outcome equation. (i.e. use probit model with bi-variate normal errors)
3. Control function approach - basically add the residuals from the first stage equation to covariates in the second stage.

for details, see Blundell & Powell(2004) or Rivers & Vuong(1988).

Comment: If I could, I would rate your answer as useful. Thank you so much